# Angular2 How to create a readOnly directive for a custom form control?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have mutiple custom form components. For example one is a input-text with label and error message. I also got a input-checkbox which is a checkbox, a label and an errromessage.

I would like to create a readOnly directive which I can place on both components. Ofcourse I could `Input() readOnly: boolean` to my components, but with many more options this would get messy.

How can I create a readOnly directive for a custom form control?